# iphone 3 / 4 background-image url constant path fails

Tags: iphone, css, background-image

I have simple jQuery code to change background image.

```
        $("#headerimg" + activeContainer).css({
        "background-image" : "url(" + photoObject.image + ")",
        "display" : "block",
        "z-index" : currentZindex
    });
```

When I insert background image as relative path it works

```
display: block; background-image: url("./wp-content/images/2013/02/turkish_gulets_for_sale_master-1350.jpg"); z-index: -375;
```

But when I insert with http it fails. (This code works all browsers that I check out.)

```
display: block; background-image: url("http://guletsforsale.org/wp-content/images/2013/02/turkish_gulets_for_sale_master-1350.jpg"); z-index: -375;
```

what could be solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use whole http path? You can remove your origin (http://guletsforsale.org) and make the link relative like that:

```
var origin = window.location.origin;
relativePath = httpPath.replace(origin, "");
```

So, now you have relative path which according you should work.

Comment: But the problem is, I use blog_url()/%category%/%postname% when page changes url path increases. sometime decreases. to use this I have to calculate all paths and replace them with ../ is it really usable?

Comment: blog_url().replace(window.location.origin, "") + "/%category%/%postname%";

It won't lower loading time almost at all. But I think the problem is somewhere else, not in your code. I just tested your websites with my iPhone 4 and the background image worked well.